# Present Embedded YouTube video with custom thumbnail

Tags: javascript, angularjs, video, youtube

I have an Angular (1.x) web application and I am trying to embed a YouTube video URL using an iframe (HTML template below). Instead of the default image presented by YouTube for the video, I would like to use a custom image. I would still like to have the play and share buttons appear as they do.

Just to clarify: The custom image is served from my own server and is not static in the sense that each video could have a different custom image.

Is there a way to achieve this? Any alternative suggestions?

```
<div class="class-under-my-control">
  <iframe width="100%" 
          ng-src="{{ youtubeURL }}"  
          frameborder="0" 
          allowfullscreen>
  </iframe>
</div>
```